# Why can't I move my character?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a game where the character can move up (not jump), left, right, and down. I'm extremely new to lwjgl so any other errors you find or if you have any tips to give me, please don't hold back.

My Code:

```
public class Player {

public float x, y, xspeed, yspeed, delta;
public long lastFrame;

public Player(){

    x=350;
    y=250;
    xspeed=1;
    }

public void drawPlayer(Texture tex, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    tex.bind();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x,y,0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex2f(width,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex2f(width,height);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex2f(0,height);
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
 }

public void playerMovement(){


    while(Keyboard.next()){

        float delta= getDelta();

        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
        xspeed = Math.max(-5, xspeed-1); 
        xspeed*=0.9;


        if (Keyboard.getEventKey()==Keyboard.KEY_W && Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            x++;
            xspeed=Math.min(5, xspeed+1);

        if (Keyboard.getEventKey()==Keyboard.KEY_A && Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            x++;
            xspeed=Math.min(5, xspeed+1);

        if (Keyboard.getEventKey()==Keyboard.KEY_S && Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            x++;
            xspeed=Math.min(5, xspeed+1);
    }
  }

public float getDelta(){

    long currentTime= getTime();
    float delta=(float)(currentTime - lastFrame);
    lastFrame=getTime();

    return delta;
}

public long getTime(){

    return (Sys.getTime() *1000 ) / Sys.getTimerResolution();

}

public void update(int xspeed, int yspeed ){

    x+=xspeed;
    y+=yspeed;

 }
}
```

Comment: use `{` brackets for if statements

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the if statements in player movement don't make sense.

```
   if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
      xspeed = Math.max(-5, xspeed-1); 
      xspeed*=0.9;
```

Here, only the first assignment depends on KEY_D, not the multiplication. Thus, the last xspeed assigment after (!) the last if "wins" all the time.

```
   if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
      xspeed = Math.max(-5, xspeed-1);
      xspeed*=0.9;
   }
```

Same for the following if statements.